# ¿Es posible validar con el operador Or un FormRequest en laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo un formulario en el cual muestro multas y consumos, y un botón que envía los elementos seleccionados. La cuestión es si se se puede hacer  que el `FormRequest` valide que uno de los dos sea enviado.

```
return [
        'consumos'=>'required',
        'multas'=>'required'
    ];
```

El código anterior no me sirve por que obliga a elegir ambos, ¿entonces se puede con formRequest? o debería validar con `javascript` antes de enviar el formulario. Gracias.

**Solución**

```
public function generarPago(Request $peticion)
{
    $num_medidor = $peticion->get('num_medidor');

    $prueba1 = Validator::make($peticion->all(), [
        'consumos' => 'required',
    ]);
    $prueba2 = Validator::make($peticion->all(), [
        'multas' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($prueba1->fails() && $prueba2->fails()) {
        return redirect('http://localhost/getHistorial/'.$num_medidor)
            ->withErrors('Para generar el pago es necesario seleccionar una multa o un consumo.')
            ->withInput();
    }else if(!$prueba1->fails()){
        foreach ($peticion->get('consumos') as $m)
        {
            $this->pconsumo($num_medidor, $m);
        }

    }else{
        foreach ($peticion->get('multas') as $m)
        {
            $this->pmulta($num_medidor, $m);
        }

    }
}

public function pmulta($num_medidor, $id)
{
    echo 'Multa '.$id. ' Cancelada! <br>';
}
public function pconsumo($num_medidor, $id)
{
    echo 'Consumo '.$id. ' Cancelado! <br>';
}
```

Comment: Si muestras el código completo de tu controlador podré integrar la solución que te he propuesto en él.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quizá la mejor solución para leer y entender el código del controlador es [dividir en dos la validación](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation) y que falle en caso de que uno de los dos no se cumpla:

```
<?php
/* Necesario para validar con Validator::make */
use Validator;
/* Normalmente usado para recibir los parámetros en el controlador */
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
/* Usado para crear una clase que actúa de controlador */
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class TuControlador extends Controller
{
  public function tu_accion(Request $peticion)
  {
    $prueba1 = Validator::make($peticion->all(), [
      'consumos' => 'required',
    ]);
    $prueba2 = Validator::make($peticion->all(), [
      'multas' => 'required',
    ]);
    if ($prueba1->fails() || $prueba2->fails()) {
      /* Hacer lo que quieras cuando falle la comprobación */
    }
    /* Hacer lo que quieras si el formulario cumple las condiciones */
  }
}
```

Otra solución (que no he probado) sería una dependencia cíclica, puede complicarse cuando hay muchas dependencias y probablemente sea más difícil de mantener:

```
return [
  'consumos' => 'required_without:multas',
  'multas' => 'required_without:consumos',
];
```

Comment: Estimado amigo muchas gracias por su comentario, las soluciones que aporto son justamente lo que necesito, y me inclino mas por la validación en el controlador, antes de aceptar su respuesta adjunto el código al post con el fin de ver si es posible mejorarlo o algún consejo para mejorar las practicas son bienvenidos saludos.

Comment: Por último te recomendaría validar en javascript y en el controlador, así el usuario tiene una mejor experiencia.